# Customize gradle script for custom output folder and exe name

Tags: spring, gradle

I am using Gradle to build my project.Script is working fine and it generates output file using task "installApp". The problem here is output folder is same as the project folder name and the executable file also creates with project name. for e.g. my project name is com.eclipse.spring.shell so the output of gradle script creates folder "com.eclipse.spring.shell" and name of the executable is also "com.eclipse.spring.shell".

SO my question is can i customize the output folder name as well executable file name in the script?
my gradle script looks like mentioned below:

```
description = '
Command Line Interface'
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {  
    compile project(':com.eclipse.spring.Framework'), project(':com.eclipse.spring.User'), project(':com.eclipse.spring.Manager'), project(':com.eclipse.spring.Test')  
    }

mainClassName = "com.eclipse.spring.Shell.RvsBootstrap"

defaultTasks 'installApp'

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    description = 'Generates gradlew[.bat] scripts'
    gradleVersion = '1.2'
}
```

Comment: You have to define a custom build script: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html

Comment: Do you mean i have to create task instead of using default task?

Comment: It seems to be the only way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the output folder name under installApp and the applicationName under startScripts.

Example:

```
installApp {
    destinationDir = file('build/install/'+'YourFolderName')
}

startScripts {
    applicationName = 'YourApplicationName'
}
```